# Write manipulated buffer to new file

Tags: c, buffer

My program tries to decrypt the data of a file by writing the file to a buffer, manipulating the buffer data, then writing the buffer to a new output file. Currently this program does not manipulate the data inside the buffer, it just writes the buffer data to the output file as is. What would be the correct way to write the manipulated data from my buffer into a new file?

```
 /*-----------------------------------------
 *swaps the nibbles of a byte
 */
unsigned char nibbleSwap(unsigned char byte){
        return( (byte & 0x0f) << 4 | (byte & 0xf0) >>4);
}

 /*-----------------------------------------
 * swaps the bits of given data
 */
unsigned char bitSwap(unsigned char byte){
        unsigned char b = nibbleSwap(byte);
        b= (b & 0xcc) >>2 | (b & 0x33) <<2;
        b= (b & 0xaa) >>1 | (b & 0x55) <<1;
        return(b);
}

int main(int argc, char**argv){
        FILE * pFile;
        char * outputFile;
        unsigned char * buffer;
        long lSize;
        size_t result;

        //gets filename from cmd line
        printf("Author: Torin Costales \n");
        for (int x=1; x<argc; x++)
                printf("Input File: %s\n",  argv[x]);
        pFile = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
        if(pFile == NULL){
                printf("OPEN ERROR");
                return -1;
        }
        //file size
        fseek (pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
        lSize= ftell(pFile);
        rewind (pFile);

        //buffer allocation
        buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc (sizeof(unsigned char)*lSize);
        if(buffer == NULL) {
                printf("MEM ERROR");
                return -1;
        }
       
        //read data from file into the buffer
        result =fread(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), lSize, pFile);
        if(result != lSize){
                printf("Read error");
                return -1;
        }
        //decrypt data, odd bytes nibbles are swapped, even bytes have bits reversed
        for(int x =0; x < sizeof(buffer); x++){
                if(x % 2 == 1){
                        nibbleSwap(buffer[x]);
                }
                else
                        bitSwap(buffer[x]);
        }

        //make output file
        if(argc >=2){
                outputFile = argv[1];
                char appendix[] = ".d";
                strncat(outputFile, appendix, 2);
                pFile= fopen(outputFile, "wb");
                printf("Output File: %s\n", outputFile);
                fwrite(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), lSize, pFile);
                fclose (pFile);
        }
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have some code already.  Did it work?  What's wrong with it?  What specific step are you getting stuck on?

Comment: Im getting stuck on the for loop when I go to decrypt the data. It doesnt seem to write the decrypted data into the buffer. When the file is written, its written with the same encrypted data, and no changes to the buffer data are made.

Comment: nibbleSwap and bitSwap will do something to their argument and return the changed number. They do not change their agument. And you don't do anything with the returned number. You may want to assign that result somewhere...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try assigning the result of `nibbleSwap` and `bitSwap` calls to `buffer[x]`, i.e. change your second for loop like so:

```
for(int x =0; x < sizeof(buffer); x++){
        if(x % 2 == 1){
                buffer[x] = nibbleSwap(buffer[x]);
        }
        else
                buffer[x] = bitSwap(buffer[x]);
}
```